# How to solve selenium invalid element state in my case?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a list of address stored in my excel. I want to search each address on google, get its corresponding zip code and store the results on my file, but I kept getting error such as selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state. The address is in intersection format, and information such as N,W,E,S,Blvd,Ave,Pkwy and etc are omitted. Geocoding didn't work out, so I'm trying to use selenium to do the scraping work.

```
import openpyxl
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Path to ChromeDriver executable
chrome_driver_path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\Projects\chromedriver.exe'

# Path to your Excel file
excel_file_path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\Projects\Just_Address.xlsx'

# Load the Excel file
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_path)
sheet = workbook.active

# Get the column index of the search items in the Excel file
search_item_column = 'A'

# Open a new Chrome browser window
service = Service(chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

# Navigate to Google
driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=McFarland+Blvd+%26+15th+St%2C+Tuscaloosa&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS965US965&oq=McFarland+Blvd+%26+15th+St%2C+Tuscaloosa&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j35i39.1507j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8')

# Iterate over the search items in Excel file
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
    search_item = row[0]  #search item is in the first column (A)

    # Find the search bar and enter the search item
    search_bar = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'gLFyf')
    search_bar.clear()
    search_bar.send_keys(search_item)
    search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    # Wait for the search results to load
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    # Extract the desired information from the search results
    search_results = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'fMYBhe')
    for result in search_results:
        cell = sheet.cell(row=sheet.max_row + 1, column=2)
        cell.value = result.text

    # Save the changes to the Excel file
    workbook.save(excel_file_path)

    # Close the browser window and quit the driver
    driver.quit()
```

I'm specificly looking to extract this information
[Search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD7k2.png)

Blow is my  traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\pythonProject\scrape\mmp2.py", line 33, in <module>
    search_bar.clear()
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\pythonProject\scrape\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 117, in clear
    self._execute(Command.CLEAR_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\pythonProject\scrape\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 395, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\pythonProject\scrape\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\pythonProject\scrape\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.110)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00FEA813+48355]
    (No symbol) [0x00F7C4B1]
    (No symbol) [0x00E85220]
    (No symbol) [0x00EAB37A]
    (No symbol) [0x00ECA73C]
    (No symbol) [0x00EA9A36]
    (No symbol) [0x00ECAA94]
    (No symbol) [0x00EDC922]
    (No symbol) [0x00ECA536]
    (No symbol) [0x00EA82DC]
    (No symbol) [0x00EA93DD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0124AABD+2539405]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0128A78F+2800735]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0128456C+2775612]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010751E0+616112]
    (No symbol) [0x00F85F8C]
    (No symbol) [0x00F82328]
    (No symbol) [0x00F8240B]
    (No symbol) [0x00F74FF7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x77C500C9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E27B4E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E27B1E+238]
```